# Validating CGI Event parameters to protect from XSS (cross site attack) in perl lauguauge

Tags: perl, cgi, xss

From the IBM AppScan report i got to know that my code is not doing any CGI EVENT_PARAMETER validation to prevent the site from XSS (Cross site scripting) attack , Link Injection (facilitates Cross-Site Request Forgery).

I tried all the below validation in my CGI.pm to check my EVENT_PARAMETERS contain any unwanted characters or not.

But nothing got worked.

Is there any other method in perl to perform validation of CGI EVENT_PARAMETERS against xss attack?.

```
sub string_param{  #my local function in cgi.pm to validate the parameter 
 # othere code snippets here
 foreach my $val (@raw){

 $val =~ s/.*<\/?(script|img|a).*//igs;
 $val =~ s/%//igs;
 $val =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]*/ /g;
 $val =~ s/[^0-9\-].*//g;
 $val = encode_entities($val);
 push( @cooked, $val );
 # returning the event parameter here
  }
```

Would like to know is there any other  CGI EVENT_PARAMETER validation method in perl to resolve the XSS cross site scripting attack.

Comment: A minimal complete example that demonstrates the vulnerability would be useful to see.

Comment: What's `EVENT_PARAMETER`? There is no such thing in CGI, so it must be an actual parameter your code takes.

Answer (score 1):

https://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html

Using the CGI cpan module you can use the subroutine escapeHTML and prevent XSS escaping user input before show it, since no html input from a user is viable, the user will be unable to insert links also.